# Having javascript act on only one item in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have the following code (coffeescript) and I have rails creating a list of subscription-videos and I want the popup to only popup on the one I hover over. But since since every video in the list has the class subscription-video no matter which I hover over it only shows the popup for the first one. What is the best way to have javascript define that I am looking for the popup id in the currently selected (one I am hovering over) subscription-video class?

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.subscription-video').hover (->
    $('#popup').show()
  ), ->
    $('#popup').hide()
```

Comment: you can't repeat ID's in a page, they are unique by definition. Please show your html

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with DOM traversal. Assuming your `subscription-video` tag and popup are in the same div:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.subscription-video').hover (->
    $(this).closest('.popup').show()
  ), ->
    $(this).closest('.popup').hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document)
    .on("mouseenter",".subscription-video", function(e){             
        $(e.target).hide(300);
    });
    $(document)
    .on("mouseleave",".subscription-video", function(e){            
         $(e.target).show(300);
    });

});
```

Also known as event delegation